# Getting input for the two matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I can't figure out how to make input for two matrix without using numpy and get exactly like X and Y below.

```
# 3x3 matrix
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]
# 3x4 matrix
Y = [[5,8,1,2],
    [6,7,3,0],
    [4,5,9,1]]
# result is 3x4
result = [[0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0]]

# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
   print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would allow you to input the values of each row separated by a `;`. So, the first example would be `12,7,3 ; 4,5,6 ; 7,8,9`.

```
matrix = input().split(';')  # read the rows, separated by ";"
matrix = [x.split(',') for x in matrix]  # read the columns, separated by ","

# convert numbers (str) to int
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        matrix[i][j] = int(matrix[i][j].strip())
```